# Google Datastore: check if ANY entity exists of given kind

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My scenario is as follows: 
I have a MapReduce job running on a new kind (=table) of entities in Datastore (using com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.inputs.DatastoreInput). the entities are created elsewhere...

so it's possible that on the first run, there will be no entities of this kind, and in such a case, I don't want to start the job at all.  so, without having any key, I want to check if, for a given kind, any entity exists or none.

couldn't find anything in the API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I figured it out, using query.
here is the code, in case it helps someone...

```
public static boolean kindExists (String kind)
{
    Query q = new Query(kind).setKeysOnly();
    PreparedQuery pq = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().prepare(q);
    return (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1))));
}
```